# Make Identity Server 4 pass a query parameter to the login controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When I go to authorize controller(implemented in Identity Server 4):

(*) `abc.com/authorize?par1=val1&par2=val2`

I am being redirected to:

(**) `abc.com/login?ReturnUrl=abc.com/abc.com%2Fauthorize%3Fpar1%3Dval1%26par2%3Dval2"`

One can notice that `ReturnUrl` equals the (*) but just being html encoded.
I would like to add `par2` value as a second parameter to the (**) url example:

`abc.com/login?ReturnUrl=abc.com/abc.com%2Fauthorize%3Fpar1%3Dval1%26par2%3Dval2&par2=val2"`

How to configure IdentityServer to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

IdentityServer is a certified `OpenId Connect` protocol implementation, and it handles your (*) request as a standard [Authorization request, which has predefined structure](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest).

The only two parameters with no limitation by the spec are the `state` which is used by clients and should be sent back with response as it is, and `acr_values` which is specially aimed for sending additional parameters to the server.

You can involve `acr_values` for your purposes the following way: `&acr_values=par2:val2` and then in [`BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/854f6195fbda10ea28190e58713937f7b6d42e7f/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L234) method of the `AccountController` you can access them as `context?.AcrValues`. You can extend `LoginViewModel` to bring the value to the layout.

Comment: I need to add additional querystring parameter of certain name. Unfortunately I can't use acr_values.

Comment: Identity server accepts [valid OAuth 2.0/OIDC parameters](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthorizationEndpoint) .

Comment: @Yoda, you can't. That's a protocol, like http, tcp, etc... you have to follow... or implement something own without guarantee that the protocol will work as expected and that your implementation will work the same way each next day

Comment: Will the `acr_values` be put in the `redirectUrl` and encoded or parsed and attached as separate parameters for the `Login` controller like I wished in the original post?

Comment: Login is just a method in AccountController, I pointed the place in that controller where acr_values could be accessed as a dictionary. When you create the request you can put into acr_values whatever you want as a space separated array of name:value pairs, then Identityserver will parse it for you. Parameters for the query between authorization endpoint and login screen are not specified by the protocol, we have to treat them as internal implementation and a subject to change at any time.

Comment: I try to access these values but context is always null in the `Index` action of `LoginController`: `var context = _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl?.ToString()).Result;`

Comment: Yes, but he used Query helpers instead to just cut from the url what he wanted, he wasn't able to access the context. If I paste  `_interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl?.ToString())` I get proper result in the Immeadiate Window but in code it's null even when I access `Result` property.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/53d3b7f5c4415a733d8392b3c3a85c3adf17646b/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/OidcReturnUrlParser.cs#L35) is the parser. it validates the url and returns null when [validation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/5d42c55f1fcaaecdc427e216b2bbcf424c0f50fe/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs#L58) fails